# How to integrate Botman in Symfony 3 (controller and view )?

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, botman

I would like to integrate a chatbot into my symfony website. So I saw that there was Botman which is a PHP framework and it meets my needs, but I find no documentation concerning its integration with Symfony.So as it is in PHP and symfony too, so I started to install it with composer and then the drivers too.

**Here are the steps I followed**

1. composer require botman/botman
2. composer require botman/driver-web
3. make a controller in my forehead

**My Controller**

```
 public function chatAction()
{
    $config = [
    // Your driver-specific configuration
    // "telegram" => [
    //    "token" => "TOKEN"
    // ]
];

   DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class);

   $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

  // Give the bot something to listen for.
$botman->hears('Hello', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello too');
});

// $botman->fallback(function($bot) {
//     $bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand these commands. Here is a list of commands I understand: ...');
// });

// Start listening
$botman->listen();

return $this->render('DoctixFrontBundle:Chat:index.html.twig');
 }
```

**My view**
For my view I have no starting point and I don't know what to do clearly, that's why i just put the css and the js of botman in it

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>BotMan Widget</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script id="botmanWidget" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
</body>
   
</html>
<script>
        var botmanWidget = {
            frameEndpoint: '/chat.html',
            introMessage: 'Hello, I am a Chatbot',
            chatServer : 'chat.php', 
            title: 'My Chatbot', 
            mainColor: '#456765',
            bubbleBackground: '#ff76f4',
            aboutText: '',
            bubbleAvatarUrl: '',
        }; 
    </script>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
```

But nothing to do, I only have a display of a piece of css and js code in my rendering.
Can help me
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use the [Botman web widget](https://botman.io/2.0/web-widget) to render the chat box.

You need three routes and three controller functions:

- One that will send back the page that contains the chatbot widget ("homepage" in the following example),
- One that will deal with the Botman logic and return the serialized answers of the bot("message" in the following example),
- One that will send back the chat frame ("chatframe" in the following example).

here is a basic example:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;


class BobotController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/message", name="message")
     */
    function messageAction(Request $request)
    {
        DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class);

        // Configuration for the BotMan WebDriver
        $config = [];

        // Create BotMan instance
        $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

        // Give the bot some things to listen for.
        $botman->hears('(hello|hi|hey)', function (BotMan $bot) {
            $bot->reply('Hello!');
        });

        // Set a fallback
        $botman->fallback(function (BotMan $bot) {
            $bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand.');
        });

        // Start listening
        $botman->listen();

        return new Response();
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('DoctixFrontBundle:Chat:homepage.html.twig');
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/chatframe", name="chatframe")
     */
    public function chatframeAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('DoctixFrontBundle:Chat:chat_frame.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And you need two views, first the chat frame `chat_frame.html.twig` (a simple copy-paste of the one provided in [Botman web widget's documentation](https://botman.io/2.0/web-widget)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>BotMan Widget</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/assets/css/chat.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="botmanWidget" src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/chat.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the page that will contain the chat widget in its bottom right corner `homepage.html.twig`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>Click on the chat button.</p>
        <script>
            var botmanWidget = {
            frameEndpoint: '{{ path("chatframe") }}',
            chatServer: '{{ path("message") }}',
            introMessage: 'Hello, I am a Chatbot',
            title: 'My Chatbot', 
            mainColor: '#456765',
            bubbleBackground: '#ff76f4',
            aboutText: ''
        };
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botman-web-widget@0/build/js/widget.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```